# Создание разных значений ИД для динамически генерируемых элементов (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Имееется код, который генерирует теги 'label' на странице.

```
  $html .=  "\n\t".
    '<label id="myID1" class="radio" style="min-height:42px;">'.
    '<input type="radio" style="float:none;" name="'.$var.'" id="'.$var.'" value="'.$item->value.'" 
'.$checked.'>'.
    $img.
    '<span style="margin-left: 10px;">'.JText::_($item->text).'</span>'.
    '</label>';
 }
$html .= "\n";
return $html;
```

Нужно чтобы у создаваемых тегов 'label'были разные ID. Пробовал использовать инкремент, а также цикл for, но желаемого результата не достиг. Я совсем недавно изучаю php, прошу помочь решить данную задачу.

Comment: В английской версии предложили же использовать `$var`. А также неясно зачем лейблу `id`

Answer (score 0):

Лейболу id для стилизации. В частности, чтобы можно было скрыть некоторый элемент на определенной странице. Я добавил следующий код:

```
$idlist = array("ida", "idb", "idc"); foreach($idlist as $id){ $html .= "\n\t". '<label id="' . $id . '" class="radio" style="min-height:42px;">'. "\n".
```

У меня на странице было 3 метода оплаты(Bank transfer, PayPal и Skrill), после добавления данного кода стало 9 (3 Bank transfer, 3 PayPal и 3 Skrill ). Как это исправить?